# Как сделать отступ сверху?

Tags: javascript

Есть меню под шапкой которое при прокрутке страницы подымается в верх, но над шапкой есть поиск и меню его перекрывает, как сделать отступ, что бы меню не доходило до верха 70px.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.fixed-div');
    $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
            $nav.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $nav.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fixed-box {
 height: 50px;
}
.fixed-div {
 height: 50px;
}
.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$h = $nav.offset().top - 70;
```

и

```
.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 top: 70px;
}
```

если я все правильно понял.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.fixed-div');
    $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $h + 70) {
            $nav.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $nav.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```